# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone

I just opened a project i havent worked for in a couple months, and just tried to compile and run it.

I immediately got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "l_OBJC_PROTOCOL_$_VideoOverviewControllerDelegate", referenced from:
    l_OBJC_CLASS_PROTOCOLS_$_FeaturedViewController in FeaturedViewController.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

and no amount of cleaning helped this error. I checked the two classes referenced in the error but couldn't find any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you don't have VideoOverviewControllerDelegate (i don't know, what it is) in linked frameworks. [How to add framework to project](http://www.thinketg.com/Company/Blogs/11-03-20/Xcode_4_Tips_Adding_frameworks_to_your_project.aspx#axzz1aZNmWDNZ).

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue as well and finally found that i had implemented the same class two times.
Check our class names for duplicates or duplicate .h or .m files.

Comment: If you had duplicate symbols, the error messages would most likely be different from what the OP is seeing.

Comment: @Mysticial has a point. The error message would be something like: `duplicate symbols found for architecture`, not what the OP has listed.

Answer (score 3):

Just be sure you didn't import a .m in your file.

```
#import "myFile.m"
```

will give you this error... 
just fix it with a

```
#import "myFile.h"
```